# Reset a page with multiple exposed filters

Tags: ajax, javascript, views

I have a view page which is the main page on my website. It is kind of a search using exposed filters. As I have many exposed filters I installed the module MEFIBS which allows me to split the exposed form into multiple blocks that you can place in different areas. I have enabled Ajax as I use the UI slider from Better Exposed Filters module. I am developing on localhost (D7).

Now, I want to include a reset button to this main page. BEF module provides "include a reset button" but in my case every exposed filter gets an own reset button which is not user friendly (this is due to the MEFIBS module).

I tried [this approach](https://www.udemy.com/blog/jquery-refresh-page/) by adding a simple html button and the script location.reload(true), expecting that the page reloads not from the browsers's cache rather than from the server. The reloading works but the filter settings don't get reseted and I don't know why.

Does anybody have expierience with that? Any advise what causes this problem? Or maybe another approach?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Are the query parameters showing in the URL?  Perhaps you could simply direct users to a clean version of the page without the parameters...

Comment: No, unfortunately there are no parameteres in the url. I guess the don't show up because of the enabled Ajax and the checked "send automatically". But thanks for your hint.